# Error while accessing EntityManager in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL to join multiple tables(Person and PersonLine) and fetch column from both the tables. While using entity manager, I get error. Can anyone please help on whats wrong below.

SearchPersonServiceImpl.java

```
package com.myc.cc.service.impl;
import static com.myc.cc.repository.SearchPersonPredicates.findPID;

@Service
public class SearchPersonServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements SearchPersonService {

@Autowired
private SearchPersonRepository personRepository;

@Transactional
@Override
public List<Person> findPnumber(Long id) { 
        Iterable<Person> person = personRepository
                .findAll(findPID(id));
        return constructList(person);
    }
}
```

SearchPersonPredicates.java

```
package com.myc.cc.repository;

public class SearchPersonPredicates {

@PersistenceContext
private static EntityManager entityManager;

public static Predicate findPID(final Long pId) { 
        QPerson qPerson = QPerson.person;
        BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
        if (pId != null) {
            booleanBuilder.and(qPerson.p_id.eq(pId));
        }
        Predicate predicate = booleanBuilder.getValue();
        JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);        //Line : 83
        QPersonLine qPersonLine = QPersonLine.personLine; 
        jpaQuery.from(qPerson); 
        jpaQuery.join(qPersonLine);
        jpaQuery.on(qPerson.p_id.eq(qPersonLine.p_id));     
        jpaQuery.where(qPerson.p_id.eq(pId)); 
        List<Person> list = jpaQuery.list(qPerson);
        logger.info("List size of Persons :"+list.size());
        return predicate;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR 5116 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/new_dev] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAProvider.getTemplates(JPAProvider.java:66)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.<init>(JPAQuery.java:44)
    at com.myc.cc.repository.SearchPersonPredicates.findPID(SearchPersonPredicates.java:83)
    at com.myc.cc.service.impl.SearchPersonServiceImpl.findPnumber(SearchPersonServiceImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.findPnumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.myc.cc.web.SearchPersonController.searchPerson(SearchPersonController.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

JPAProvider.class

```
public static JPQLTemplates getTemplates(EntityManager em) {
    // detect by delegate
    for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, JPQLTemplates> entry : mappings.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(em.getDelegate().getClass())) {     //Line : 66
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    // detect by properties
    for (String key : em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().keySet()) {
        key = key.toLowerCase();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JPQLTemplates> entry : templatesByName.entrySet()) {
            if (key.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return JPQLTemplates.DEFAULT;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: SearchPersonPredicates has not been annotated with Component. So Spring will not autowire the persistenceContext

Comment: Out of curiosity, Why are you executing your query inside the Predicate ? You dont seem to be doing anything with the list either ?

Comment: Even if it would be annotated with `@Component` it would fail as auto wiring static fields isn't supported. Also why aren't you just using a HQL using a predicate seems a bit overdone for this.

Comment: @ArunM I tried adding @Component and got error as 
`Persistence annotations are not supported on static fields` . I  am new to Spring boot and QueryDSL. I referred to a sample from net and was trying to implement similar to that. Since I am getting error while joining I am just trying to display the list

Comment: @M.Deinum  Application have a search page where the user have 20 to 25 search fields. Those fields can be empty or it can contain data. So based on that we have to form query and we thought QueryDSL would be a choice for implementing it.

Comment: You can use QueryDSL but your way seems a bit convoluted. Instead I suggest using Spring Data JPA (which according to the tags you are using) and use a [`QueryDslSpecificationExecutor`]() which can save you some trouble . See [this](http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion. The repository interface extends `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`. Can i clarify that instead of `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`,is it suggested to use `QueryDslSpecificationExecutor`

Comment: That was a typo on my behalve, mixed `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`. However the real problem, imho, is that you are using the `EntityManger`... Why? Spring Data will execute the query, you are now executing it yourself (at least trying to) and later on spring data will do it again, your query will be executed twice. Just remove that part.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry. I dont understand clearly.Are you suggesting to remove `entitymanager`. If not using `EntityManager` , I got error in the application. Exactly at this line 'List<Person> list = jpaQuery.list(qPerson);'

Comment: @M.Deinum. My application is in Spring boot. It would be helpful if you can suggest a way(other than QueryDSL) to implement complex search which involves multiple tables and sub queries(query is formed based on user input). Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be executing the query in the first place... Why are you even trying to do that! You should be constructing predicates NOT execute queries, Spring Data will create the query based on the the predicates and execute it.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Thanks. In that way I formed a predicate and returned that predicate to ServiceImpl class, and I got results from DB(with findAll()) when query involved with one single table with help of repository class. But for join tables(Person and PersonLine), can you suggest me how to form and use predicates with help of repository class. The search page has to display data from both tables.

Comment: `BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();`
`booleanBuilder.and(qPerson.p_id.eq(pId));`
`Predicate predicate = booleanBuilder.getValue();`In this way I can form predicates and using findAll() I got results from DB. But I am not aware how to join multiple tables this way.

Comment: Your query returns `Person` instances, so not sure what you would expect had happend? If there is a relation between the 2 it should be in your JPA model...

Answer (score 0):

You should add @Repository annotation to your class;

```
@Repository
public class SearchPersonPredicates {
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I have `SearchPersonRepository` interface which extends `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person>`. Do I have to add `@Repository` in this class or in `SearchPersonPredicates`.